# How would I strip something from being encased between colons and retrieve the last one on it

Tags: node.js, json, pcap, tshark

I've been working tirelessly at this pcap analysing script and finally got "somewhere" but now I have the issue of stripping the protocol from the line thats encasing it with colons:

IE:

```yaml
eth:ethertype:arp
```

or

```yaml
eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:ssh
```

I'm trying to get the last value from each like `ssh` or `arp` these objects change in sizes (using tshark pcap - JSON file)

Comment: String split at `:` char and then array[array.length-1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.  You can use `.split(":")` and then take the last item from the resulting array.

```js
let str = "eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:ssh";

let splits = str.split(":");
console.log(splits[splits.length - 1]);
```

You can use a regex like:

```js
let str = "eth:ethertype:ip:tcp:ssh";
let regex = /:([^:]+)$/;
let matches = str.match(regex);
if (matches) {
    console.log(matches[1]);
} else {
    console.log("no matches");
}
```

Comment: Lol, I was just about to ask when you first answered what you meant by `.split(":")`  but then SO updated your answer as I clicked to comment.

Tested it in the live development and works like a charm, thanks for the tip; must remember this one for future reference. @jfriend00